# onRequestPermissionsResult not called

Tags: java, android

Marshmallow Runtime Permission onRequestPermissionsResult was nor Called While running playstore Build Apk but working fine the normal debuging Apk.Anyone help me..Thanks.

#### Here is my code

```
private void EnablePermissions() 
{
// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO },
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // result of the request.
    }
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "checkSelfPermission ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        Log.d("Permission Denied", "Permission Failed to enable");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Failed to enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

OnRequestPermissionResult Method

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    try {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                ChatActivity();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied Chat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.LOG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: it´s only working on marshmallow and above. lower versions will ignore this request....

Comment: yes i am doing my testing nexus 5 marshmallow 6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way of doing it https://stackoverflow.com/a/35495372/4493133 . I am doing basically the same thing below.

Here is an example on how I made it work for my code

```
private void requestStoragePermission() {
        /*
         We don't have permission so prompt the user
         If permission is not granted control goes to onRequestPermissionResult
          */
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
```

onRequestPermissionsResult method:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("PERMISSION", "Storage permission granted");
                } else {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                        showMessageOkCancel("You need to allow access to Storage to use the offline timetables",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        switch (which) {
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                requestStoragePermission();
                                                break;
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Storage permission required to continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                        .show();
                                                finishAffinity();
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable storage permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        finishAffinity();
                    }
                }

        }

    }
```

showMessageOkCancel method:

```
private void showMessageOkCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

Explanation:

**In your main code**, you only requestStoragePermission().

onRequestPermissionsResult will run whether the permission is granted or not.

**If the permission is granted**, then good, that's all.

**If the permission is not granted**, then shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() will return true if it is the first time asking for permission. I then prompt another dialog with some explanation to give another chance to the user to enable the permission.

However if "**don't ask again**" is checked, then shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false. The requestPermissions dialog will not pop up anymore. The user has to go to **enable the permission manually**.

Note you don't have to finishAffinity(). You can just disable the portion of the code that needs that permission.

Comment: I am using the above method also but i have same problem in Activity and fragment Activity OnRequestPermissionResult not called.

Comment: EnablePermissions() should only have what I did in requestStoragePermission(). The rest of the code is in onRequestPermissionsResult(). Make sure you put onRequestPermissionsResult() in the Activity that calls EnablePermissions().

Comment: Then you only call EnablePermissions() in your code, it should work... If it doesn't show me your code