# Android Marshmallow and Above Device - how to know “Never ask again” is checked by the user

Tags: permissions, media, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-gallery

I want to request for the permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for getting Media data.

But before requesting for that permission, i want to know whether it is blocked by the user by checking "Never ask again" check box.

Is there a proper way to know "Never ask again" for a permission?

So if I can understand whether "Never show again" is clicked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like similar question has been asked before you can get your answer here [How Do We Distinguish Never-Asked From Stop-Asking in Android M's Runtime Permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928868/how-do-we-distinguish-never-asked-from-stop-asking-in-android-ms-runtime-permis)