# How to know if Android Permissions request is prompting the user or not?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I understand how to request permissions (in my case, Bluetooth related) in Android using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`, but I need to know if the user is no longer being prompted to answer the question about permissions. In other words...

- When they first come to the screen where I need to use Bluetooth permissions, I request permissions from them. Let's assume they tap `Deny` so I don't have BT permissons.
- When I set up that UI, if I don't yet have permissions, I show a UI to let them know that this particular feature isn't available until grant Bluetooth permissions.
- Part of that UI is a `Grant Bluetooth Permissions...` button they can tap to start the `requestPermissions()` process again.
- Let's assume they tap `Deny` again.
- If they tap the `Grant Bluetooth Permissions...` button a third time, my app will try to `requestPermissions()` but will just instantly get a denial and the user will not be prompted.

At that point, I need to know that they aren't being asked anymore, because I need to update the UI to remove the `Grant Bluetooth Permissions...` button and instead tell them they will need to grant permissions via the Settings app and give them a button that will jump them to the right screen in the Settings app.

But I can't find a way to determine whether or not the system is actually going to prompt the user with the Allow/Deny popup.

I've looked at `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` which is supposed to let us know whether or not we should popup any kind of explanation for why we're about to ask them for permissions. However, that returns `false` before the first permissions request, `true` before the second request, and then `false` again for all requests after that which is potentially the time when I need to change my UI. So that doesn't tell me whether or not it's going to popup the Allow/Deny dialog.

How can I determine whether or not the Allow/Deny will be presented so that I can properly configure my UI? It seems like at this particular version of Android, it will ask twice and then stop, but I don't particularly want to hard code that specific behavior into my logic because the next version of Android could start behaving differently and then my UI won't be correct.

Comment: This is close to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31928868/115145) from back when this stuff was introduced.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, unless I'm missing something, I'm not really seeing an actual solution in there. You articulated it perfectly, a boolean trying to represent 3 states. So, how do I determine State 3? The "never ask again" checkbox isn't in the UI anymore, so that part has already changed. I think it's just implied by Denying twice.

Comment: Pretty much yes. The answers describe various and sundry workarounds.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, yeah, so just workarounds but not a proper solution. Ok, thanks.