# ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission error emulator only

Tags: android, android-emulator, geolocation

I'm having a weird error while using the emulator ONLY.
I found one question that has the same issue 9 months ago with no answers at all...

I'm using google play services locations to get locations in my app and I'm sure of my manifest permissions and everything works perfectly on my phone, the problem occurs when using an emulator only, and I tried different emulators on both my iMac and Windows machines.

I doubt that emulators don't support this basic function!

here is my manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.orderme.ordermeandroid" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

and here is where the exception is firing:

```
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
```

stack trace:

```
08-26 14:01:19.699  10157-10157/com.orderme.ordermeandroid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.orderme.ordermeandroid, PID: 10157
java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzg$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzc$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzf.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzi.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
        at com.orderme.ordermeandroid.Main.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:184)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzh(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.zznt(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.onConnected(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzi$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzoD(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzs(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzoF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: I also got this error on emulator, have you tested in a device It was working fine when I tested it on a real device!!

Comment: The emulators dont have google play services installed, install them and see if you get same error again

Comment: thank you for the comment, but the code snippet in the post is taken from the onConnected method of the googleapiclient, which means everything before is working and it's connecting as well, besides, if the services are not available I should get error on using the classes not the permission !

Comment: "here is where the exception is firing" -- please post your stack trace.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

My guess is that you are running this on an Android 6.0+ emulator and you have a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher.

In that case, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` are part of [the Android 6.0 runtime permission system](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html). Either revise your app to participate in this system, or drop your `targetSdkVersion` below 23.

Comment: thank you! this was it, although I hated the new permissions method but it solved the problem

Comment: I updated my phone the day before a demo and started freaking out because of this. Thank you, you saved me.

Comment: I am new to Android development. Would you revise your reply to answer the question of "Either revise your app to participate in this system, or drop your targetSdkVersion below 23."? Thanks.

Comment: I dropped the target to 20 , but it still happens. any ideas ? thanks

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: @BVtp If your device is with api23 and your target sdk 20 if it is still crashing then may be you denied pemission for gps from setting. Go To setting>Apps>Select your app> Permission and give GPS pemission.

Comment: @VindhyaPratapSingh Hello, that's work for me, but how to do that in the code I'm really adding the permission in AndroidManifest.xml but it's still the issue **please add the permission** !!! please I'm stuck

Comment: @Gha Sorry for late response, you can find code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719047/android-m-check-runtime-permission-how-to-determine-if-the-user-checked-nev may be it helps you

Answer (score 15):

in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app

How to check if you have the permission:

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

How to request the permissions you need :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}
```

How to access the result of the request :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission was granted, yay! Do the task you need to do.

        } else {

            // permission denied, boo! Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
        }
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Source : http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Learn more about permissions : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Permissions

Answer (score 4):

You can not get the current location from emulator. But you can emulate it to test your code. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator) you can find how to emulate.

**EDIT1:**
There is a note [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

> Note: If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER.)

You should use only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. Maybe this helps.

Comment: I have tried this before, didn't solve it, I don't mind getting null locations I'm handeling this, the error as you can see is from the PERMISSION,

Comment: yeah tried this as well ^_^ , I think commonsWare's answer is the one I'm trying it now

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by a new feature for Android 6.0. hope its work...

*Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.*

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

To get around the issue when the permission is not explicitly granted, I had put in a check to wrap location service calls (as per the Google Documentation, slightly modified).

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Execute location service call if user has explicitly granted ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION..
}
```

The Google Documentation also steps through how to request for the permissions that are needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

some times manifest have a missing line granting the permission of ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. so you need to mention it in the manifest.

I did this and my problem was solved.

This generally happens because we have given the permission in the manifest so the app would create a problem as it would not be allowed to access the permissions and the file would crash.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```