# How to remove "Never ask again" text in this popup?

Tags: android, android-permissions, permission-denied

How can I request the permission popup without “Never ask again” text?

Here java Code ,

```
    if 
 (intent.getAction().equals("com.finish.canceltrip.DriverMapActivity")) {
                if (!checkAccessFineLocationPermission() || !checkAccessCoarseLocationPermission() || !checkWriteExternalStoragePermission()) {
                    requestPermission();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(DriverMapActivity.this, DriverMapActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("availability", "Yes");
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);

                }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you understand the purpose of this. It's not your choice.

Comment: If user choose never ask again option means, it can't ask next time . So how they Know  to view the current location in that app.

Comment: @Ana you have handle that by codding and your logic

Comment: Then u can use LOLIPOP Device LOL

Comment: If they **specifically** choose not to give your app that permission and **don't ever** want to be asked again, then it's their choice, not yours.

Comment: Details how a **user** can remove it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609834/how-to-forget-the-never-ask-again-choice-in-android-m-runtime-permission-dialo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I request the permission popup without “Never ask again” text?

**NO you can not remove “Never ask again”**  from Permission Dialog

try this this hack if user selects **Never ask again**

**ask for permission like this**

```
 btnCurrentLocationSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String permission = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;


                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, permission)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
                        checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(SearchCityClass.this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchCityClass.this, new String[]
                            {permission}, requestCode);

                } else {
                    isPermissionGranted(true);
                }
            }

        });
```

than handle permission result in **onRequestPermissionsResult**

```
    @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (requestCode == requestCode) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    isPermissionGranted(true);
                } else {

                    isPermissionGranted(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

than create a method like this

```
public void isPermissionGranted(boolean permission) {
        if (!permission) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SearchCityClass.this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(SearchCityClass.this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // you need to perform all action here if user grants the permission
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No u can not remove **Never ask again** from that dialog

If the user declines again the app should either shut down if it absolutely needs that permission or keep running with limited functionality.

If the user reconsiders (and selects re-try), the permission is requested again. This time the prompt looks like this: