# File cant be created on Asus Nexus 7

Tags: android

i am developing on Asus nexus 7, and i am writing data to file on the internal storage. at run time i receive the below posted logcat output which casese the App
to terminate.

the same App tested against Samsung galaxx note 3 and it worked fine without crashing

i want to know how to fix these error when tesing against Asus nexux 7 and why that is happening.

Note: the required permission for writing on the external storage is added
please let me know what i am missing in the code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**logcat**:

```
: +++++ isExternalStorageMounted() +++++
11-26 15:53:51.329 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 D/IOCtrl: isExternalStorageMounted(): -> media state: mounted
11-26 15:53:51.330 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 D/IOCtrl: dir: /storage/emulated/0/CAN_BUS already exists
11-26 15:53:51.330 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 D/IOCtrl: file: Test_00.txt will be created
11-26 15:53:51.330 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at com.example.com.bt_11.IOCtrl.createFile(IOCtrl.java:87)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at com.example.com.bt_11.ActConnect2$ATRx.onPreExecute(ActConnect2.java:844)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at com.example.com.bt_11.ActConnect2$ATConnect.onPostExecute(ActConnect2.java:702)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at com.example.com.bt_11.ActConnect2$ATConnect.onPostExecute(ActConnect2.java:574)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-26 15:53:51.331 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-26 15:53:51.332 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
11-26 15:53:51.332 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
11-26 15:53:51.332 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 W/System.err:  ... 14 more
11-26 15:53:51.332 24003-24003/com.example.com.bt_11 E/IOCtrl: <<createFile>>:  Error creating file: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Which version are your device using?

Comment: @FireSun actuall i do not know..but the last software update was few minutes ago...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yes, i mentioned that in my question, and the same App was tested on samsung galaxy note 3 and it is working fine

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla yes,, i mentioned that in my question above

Comment: are you using Android 6.0, right? Did you use the new permission check?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla what is that?

Comment: @LetsamrIt this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31925748/3743245