# android 6 permission dialog missing checkbox for never ask again

Tags: android, location

Does anyone know how to force the "Never ask again" checkbox to not show when requesting Location permission in Android 6?  Sometimes it shows. Sometimes it doesn't. Haven't figured out why.

Comment: It is supposed to appear the second and subsequent times that you request the same permission, where the user had rejected it from the dialog previously.

Comment: @CommonsWare It this still actual in new versions of Android? Where can I find official info about this?

Comment: "It this still actual in new versions of Android?" -- it showed up the last time I tried it on Android 10. "Where can I find official info about this? " -- https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#explain

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this answer: [Android M - check runtime permission - how to determine if the user checked "Never ask again"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719047/android-m-check-runtime-permission-how-to-determine-if-the-user-checked-nev/31925748#31925748)

This is kinda what you need to do; call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` again inside `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` after they respond POSITIVE to your Dialog box explaining why this permission required.