# In onRequestPermissionsResult grantResults on some device return empty when user decline the permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, permission-denied, runtime-permissions

**In Shot:**, In `onRequestPermissionsResult` grantResults on some device return empty and some device have a value `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` when user decline the permission.

I have implmeneted a solution for identify user has selected **accepted** ,**deny** and **deny with don't ask again** for run time permission,based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/31925748/2941375 answer.

as per many docs i have seen,if user decline permission then it returns `grantResults` empty

Code i have used `else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)` so in `else if` part it throw Arrayindexoutofbound exception

> i have tested code when user decline permission `grantResults` is not
>   emplty for my case,but i have seen crash report on fabric console for
>   `grantResults` there is many crash with `arrayindexoutofbound`,

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PermissionManager.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION_ACCESS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    DefineLocationService.start(this);
                    startNextActivity(0);
                } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    boolean showRationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permissions[0]);
                    if (!showRationale) {
                        // user also CHECKED "never ask again"
                        // you can either enable some fall back,
                        // disable features of your app
                        // or open another dialog explaining
                        // again the permission and directing to
                        // the app setting
                        startNextActivity(ARTIFICIAL_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    } else if (!PermissionManager.MY_REQUESTED_DIALOG) {
                        PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(this);
                    } else {
                        startNextActivity(0);
                    }
                } else {
                    startNextActivity(ARTIFICIAL_DELAY_MILLIS);
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

**can anyone have any explanation for this,why some device return `grantResults` empty and some device return `grantResults` have value with decline when user decline permission.**

i have tested many time but `grantResults` never empty on my side,but there is crash on console,it means in some case it is empty and `grantResults[0]` throw the exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])):

> Note: It is possible that the permissions request interaction with the user is interrupted. In this case you will receive empty permissions and results arrays which should be treated as a cancellation.

How you want to deal with cancellation is totally up to you (re-ask for permission, treat it as a denial, etc), so just make sure to account for that case in your code.

Comment: is there anyway,using that i can reproduce this issue? i mean interrupted the interaction with user.

Comment: You can rotate your device while the permission prompt is up.

Comment: @ianhanniballake That doesn't work, the permission prompt stays there.

Comment: The only way I found to reproduce it is with "Don't keep Activities" enabled, but then, all subsequent permission requests fail with empty `grantResults` coming. So the "totally up to you" doesn't really apply… Any help to deal with it properly is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when the `TargetSdk` version was lower than required for the permission. (In my case it was `POST_NOTIFICATIONS`).
Once I changed it to API version 33 everything started to work as expected.