# Can't get IMEI number on first install

Tags: android, imei

I am trying to get the IMEI number of the android device.I am able to get it too, but the application doesn't return the IMEI in the first Install.
i need to restart the application.
Can anyone tell me where I am Wrong?
Thanks in advance

```
    public class RootActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE = 1;
    TextView tv ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.TV_imei);
        tv.setText(showPhoneStatePermission());

    }private String showPhoneStatePermission() {
        String imei ="ERROR";
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE);
        } else {
            imei=getIMEI();
        }
        return imei;
    }

    private String  getIMEI() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId().trim();
        return deviceId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        showPhoneStatePermission();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tv.setText(showPhoneStatePermission())` will only get called once in `OnCreate()`. After permission granted in `onRequestPermissionsResult` you did not set text . 
You need to cal `setText()` after `onRequestPermissionsResult`.
You can use

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    tv.setText(showPhoneStatePermission());
}
```

If this is just a sample then Okay . If not then you are missing Permission handling in your code . You need to handle Rational too . Look at [android-m-check-runtime-permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719047/android-m-check-runtime-permission-how-to-determine-if-the-user-checked-nev)

Comment: Thank you so much.This is a sample. I will however handle the Rational too.