# Android - deny and don't ask again camera permission

Tags: android, permissions

how to verify deny and don't ask again on camera permission android ?
I can check when it is denied, but I want to see when the user checks not to ask again

Comment: Is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719047/android-m-check-runtime-permission-how-to-determine-if-the-user-checked-nev ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` method inside `onRequestPermissionsResult`, some doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#explain)

another way would be to use `PermissionChecker`, flag which may interest you is [PERMISSION_DENIED_APP_OP](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/PermissionChecker#PERMISSION_DENIED_APP_OP)

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!